# ios 7 uitableview selected cell loses border after beginupdates

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm using `[beginUpdated]` to expand and collapse cells in my tableview. Works as expected however there is a side effect. The top border of the selected cell disappears. To repro make a tableview with selection style none. Use the code below you will see that selecting a row makes the border disappear. Any suggestions? I've tried unsetting separator style and resetting to singleLine. I've tried `layoutIfNeeded`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

This seems to be core SDK error because I reproduced in a new project with nothing but the code above and cell selection style of none.

Any work arounds? Using a 1 px UIView as a pseudo border is not an option because comps call for a group style look and figuring out if a reuseable cell should have inset or full border for every cell is just not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deselecting the cell after the updates.

Objective-C:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [tableView beginUpdates];
   [tableView endUpdates];
   [tableView delesectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
}
```

Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableview.beginUpdates()
    tableview.endUpdates()
    tableview.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```